# Django admin panel has a weird look after upgrade

Tags: python, css, django

Right after upgrade to Django `3.1.2` I went to my admin panel. Main page has a standard look with no bugs. But as soon as I click on any object, I see this picture.

[image: Bug picture]

Logs also look OK.

```
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1789
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5723
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 363
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/actions.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6766
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6918
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/urlify.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8941
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1360
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/prepopulate.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1530
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6190
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 280364
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /admin-extended/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14892
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js HTTP/1.1" 200 128820
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 331
[28/Oct/2020 15:04:52] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 331
```

So I consider I don't have any problems with getting needed CSS files. What's the problem? Is it my mistake?

EDIT1: When I uninstall Django and install Django `3.0.9` everything works OK. The problem is in update...

SOLUTION:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

Comment: Also, clear the cache and try again.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu thanks! Your advice is like a magic. Everything works right now.